# Regex to match a phrase without a phrase within it

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JavaScript regex to match the following:

```
afoobar
```

and

```
foobars
```

and

```
afoobars
```

but not the exact phrase

```
foobar
```

What I have so far is:

```
^(?!foobar).*$
```

as found on other posts, but this doesn't seem to match the case of:

```
foobars
```

I feel like I'm close, but can't seem to figure out what to add.

Thanks for any help.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for all of the answers - my question was not phrased exactly right. I also need the regex to match everything else. So it shouldn't need to have "foobar" in it to be a match. But if the string is EXACTLY foobar, then it shouldn't be a match.

Comment: So you want to match anything as long as it is not precisely "foobar"? why use regex? why not just check if `string != "foobar"`

Comment: Why complicate this. Obviously, you want to conditionally focus on 'foobar'. Use string functions. If 'foobar' found in string, qualify its `/a?foobars|afoobars?/`.

Comment: `but not the exact phrase 'foobar'` - What exactly do you mean by this statement?

Comment: @OGHaza because the code isn't actually in JavaScript - it's a configuration. I just mentioned JavaScript to be clear about what regex engine would be evaluating it. I don't really know the differences between them but I assumed there are

Comment: Fair play, there are indeed many differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
.*foobar.+|.+foobar.*
```

Or more simply:

```
.foobar|foobar.
```

Or possibly:

```
(?!^foobar$).*foobar
```

Or if you need to match any words that contains `foobar` (but not `foobar` itself) that appear as part of a larger string, you could use something like this ([**Demo**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cb%5Cw%2afoobar%5Cw%2b%5Cb%7C%5Cb%5Cw%2bfoobar%5Cw%2a%5Cb&input=This%20foobar%20is%20afoobar%20a%20foobars%20test%20afoobars.)):

```
\b\w*foobar\w+\b|\b\w+foobar\w*\b
```

Also note, if you're just trying to match any string that is *not* `foobar`, use this:

```
(?!^foobar$)^.*$
```

Or even easier, just test for exactly what you don't want to match, and accept everything else, as in:

```
function notFoobar(input) { return 'foobar' !== input; }
```

Comment: +1 Good answer didnt think of the first way you did it, only thing is '.' can match spaces and none of these account for the case of a space before and after foobar. Try \S instead of '.'

Comment: @Srb1313711 It's not clear if OP wants to match the whole string, or words within a string, but I see your point.

Comment: OP uses `^$` anchors in his attempt, so fair assumption I would say

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks for the answer. I can't write the function because this isn't actually JavaScript code - it's a configuration. But the (?!^foobar$)^.*$ regex you provided worked for my needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: ^(?!foobar[s]**).*$

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^(?!.*?\bfoobar\b).*?foobar.*$
```

This will match afoobars but won't match `foobar`

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wU9yB0

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer based on the new requirements:

`.+$(?<!^foobar)`

This says, match everything one or more times, including the end of the line--unless you look behind you and see only foobar anchored to the beginning of the line with nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Probably too much potential for false matches depending on what the test cases look like. +1

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternation - `a?foobars|afoobars?`